# Input field gets de-selected everytime I press a key in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having an issue with text based inputs in React. When the onChange event is fired for an input, the input will be deselected. The  components are controlled. They get their value from the top level form component. I am guessing this is happening because the components are re rendering but I am not sure what is causing this to happen

Here is my App.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar/NavigationBar.js';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo.js';
import SearchForm from './components/SearchForm/SearchForm.js';
import SearchFilter from './components/SearchFilter/SearchFilter.js';
import ReviewComponent from './components/ReviewComponent/ReviewComponent.js';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchfield: '', 
      searchresults: {}
    }

    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onSearchClick = this.onSearchClick.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
  }

  onSearchClick() {
    fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${this.state.searchfield}&key=&type=restaurant`)
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(results => {this.setState({ searchresults: results})})
      .then(results => {console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.searchresults))});
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter> {/* using react-router-dom for routing */}
          <NavigationBar />  {/* for navigation through the app, always rendered */}
          <Logo />   {/* a logo for the RestrauntReviewsTool */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' 
              exact 
              component={() => <SearchForm searchfield={this.state.searchfield} onInputChange={this.onInputChange} onSearchClick={this.onSearchClick} /> } 
            />  
            <Route 
              path='/searchfilter' 
              component={() => <SearchFilter searchresults={this.searchresults} /> } 
            />  

            <ReviewComponent path='/reviewcomponent' component={ReviewComponent} /> {/* final restaurant details */}
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Here is the SearchForm.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const SearchForm = ({ onInputChange, onSearchClick, searchfield }) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <p className='f3'>
                {'Search here for restaurants, maybe make an api fetch here and populate data in the SearchFilter component'}
            </p>
            <div className='center'>
                <div className='form center pa4 br3 shadow-5'>
                    <input className='f4 pa2 w-70 center' type='text' value={searchfield} onChange={onInputChange}/>
                    <button className='w-30 grow f4 ph3 pv2 dib white bg-light-purple' onClick={onSearchClick}>
                    <Link to ='/searchfilter'>
                    Search   
                    </Link>    
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change component to render in your router.
[Pass props to a component rendered by React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)

> “When you use the component props, the router uses React.createElement
>   to create a new React element from the given component. That means if
>   you provide an inline function to the component attribute, you would
>   create a new component every render. This results in the existing
>   component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just
>   updating the existing component.”

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar/NavigationBar.js';
import Logo from './components/Logo/Logo.js';
import SearchForm from './components/SearchForm/SearchForm.js';
import SearchFilter from './components/SearchFilter/SearchFilter.js';
import ReviewComponent from './components/ReviewComponent/ReviewComponent.js';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchfield: '', 
      searchresults: {}
    }

    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onSearchClick = this.onSearchClick.bind(this);
  }

  onInputChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({searchfield: event.target.value});
  }

  onSearchClick() {
    fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=${this.state.searchfield}&key=&type=restaurant`)
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(results => {this.setState({ searchresults: results})})
      .then(results => {console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.searchresults))});
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter> {/* using react-router-dom for routing */}
          <NavigationBar />  {/* for navigation through the app, always rendered */}
          <Logo />   {/* a logo for the RestrauntReviewsTool */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' 
              exact 
              render={() => <SearchForm searchfield={this.state.searchfield} onInputChange={this.onInputChange} onSearchClick={this.onSearchClick} /> } 
            />  
            <Route 
              path='/searchfilter' 
              render={() => <SearchFilter searchresults={this.searchresults} /> } 
            />  

            <ReviewComponent path='/reviewcomponent' component={ReviewComponent} /> {/* final restaurant details */}
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```